# Mule - call a controller from inside onCall() method of java class

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, mule

I am working on a project which is a **mavenized web application** having **Mule support** in it. There is requirement to call **controller** from inside a **java class** which implements **Callable** interface. I achieved it by creating an object of controller but it is against MVC rules. Then i tried to use **@Autowired annotation** but it doesn't work in **onCall()** method. Is there any solution by which i can call a controller method from java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring to inject the controller into a field of the **Callable** bean.